# XAML - Style for label and textbox

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I would like to know if it's possible to create a style for label and textbox at the same time. It avoids me to duplicate every style.

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource Style1}" Text="Label" />
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource Style1}" />
```

How can I have a style for both ?

```
<Style x:Key="Style1" TargetType="{x:Type ???????}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,20,0" />
</Style>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Indeed, I didn't search for those words, it's perfect. Thanks bud :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Style Element, Set the Target Type as

```
TargetType="{x:Type Control}"
```

or just

```
TargetType="Control"
```